# How do i only remove "http://" and "http://www"?

Tags: php

I wanna have urls stored like in example;

http://sample.com/index.php               ->        "sample.com/index.php"
http://www.sample.com/eng/index.php       ->        "sample.com/eng/index.php"

How can i remove the begining part only in php?

Comment: str_replace('http://', '', $url);

Comment: What have you even tried so far?

Comment: You should read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask questions on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not just use str_replace and using regular expressions seem overkill as well. Keep it simple and test for the beginning of the strings and just use the substring of what you actually want:

```
function trimUrl($url)  {
  if (strpos($url, 'http://www.') === 0) {
    return substr($url, 11);
  } 
  if (strpos($url, 'http://') === 0) {
    return substr($url, 7);
  } 
  return $url;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure str_replace is slower than strpos + substr?

Comment: The issue here isn't computation time is what happens with input like: `http://www.foo.bar/?url=http://www.foo.baz`? Although correct encoding might prevent such errors.

Comment: Thought so, just wasn't sure if you meant the computation time as well. +1 from me.